# sencha touch build native to create apk file

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-command

I'm a sencha touch new developer,there is a problem confusing me for two weeks!!
I use sencha CMD to build native app by 'sencha app build native' and then get the process log like this below,by the way ,there are some messy code while creating files,why?
Please help me,thanks a lot !!

```
    Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[INF] 
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF] 
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF] 
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-path:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-environment:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-shell:
[INF] 
[INF] init-cmd:
[INF]      [echo] Using Sencha Cmd from D:\senchacmd\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.1.45 for D:\wamp\www\myapp\build.xml
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init-defaults:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-defaults:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init-defaults:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-build:
[INF] 
[INF] refresh:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-refresh:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Loading classpath entry D:\wamp\www\myapp\touch\src
[INF] Loading classpath entry D:\wamp\www\myapp\app.js
[INF] Loading classpath entry D:\wamp\www\myapp\app
[INF] Loading classpath entry D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\temp\native\myapp\sencha-compiler\app
[INF] Loading classpath entry D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\temp\native\myapp\sencha-compiler\app
[INF] Concatenating output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/temp/native/myapp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] Adding external reference : @full-page => @overrides
[INF] Loading classpath entry D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\temp\native\myapp\sencha-compiler\cmd-packages.js
[INF] Adding external reference : Ext.util.Observable => D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/temp/native/myapp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] 
[INF] -refresh-app:
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to D:\wamp\www\myapp/bootstrap.json
[INF] 
[INF] -refresh:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-refresh:
[INF] 
[INF] resolve:
[INF] 
[INF] js:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-js:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] -compile-js:
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[INF] Concatenating output to file D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native/myapp/app.js
[INF] 
[INF] -js:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-js:
[INF] 
[INF] resources:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-resources:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-inherit-resources:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-copy-resources:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] -resources:
[INF] merging resources into D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp\resources
[INF] merging resources into D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp
[INF] merged 0 resources into D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp
[INF] 
[INF] -after-copy-resources:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-inherit-resources:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-resources:
[INF] 
[INF] sass:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-sass:
[INF] 
[INF] -compass-compile-theme-package:
[INF] 
[INF] -compass-compile-theme-folders:
[INF] 
[INF] -compass-compile-sass-dir:
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
identical ../css/app.css 
[INF] 
[INF] -compass-compile:
[INF] 
[INF] -sass:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-sass:
[INF] 
[INF] slice:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-slice:
[INF] 
[INF] -slice-images:
[INF] 
[INF] -slice:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-slice:
[INF] 
[INF] page:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-page:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF] 
[INF] -copy-app-resources:
[INF] Copying page resources to D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp
[INF] copying D:\wamp\www\myapp\resources\css\app.css to D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp\resources\css\app.css
[INF] 
[INF] -generate-deltas:
[INF] 
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] -build-standalone-json-manifest:
[INF] Writing content to D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native/myapp/app.json
[INF] 
[INF] -build-output-page:
[INF] 
[INF] -build-output-microload-page:
[INF] Writing content to D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native/myapp/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native/myapp/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native/myapp/index.html
[INF]    [delete] Deleting: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native\myapp\microloader.js
[INF] 
[INF] -generate-cache-manifest:
[INF] 
[INF] -page:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-page:
[INF] 
[INF] native-package:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-native-package:
[INF] 
[INF] -native-package-mobile:
[INF]      [echo] Building all specified mobile packager configs.
[INF]      [echo] 
[INF]      [echo]     Processing Mobile Packager config file
[INF]      [echo]         config: D:\wamp\www\myapp/packager.json
[INF]      [echo]         inputPath: D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native/myapp
[INF]      [echo]         outputPath: D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native-package-mobile/myapp/packager.json
[INF]      [echo] Running mobile packager action build on file D:\wamp\www\myapp/packager.temp.json
[ERR] 
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\src\com\xiubo\myapp
Added file D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\src\com\xiubo\myapp\STActivity.java
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\values
Added file D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\values\strings.xml
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\layout
Added file D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\layout\main.xml
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\drawable-xhdpi
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\drawable-hdpi
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\drawable-mdpi
Created directory D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\res\drawable-ldpi
Added file D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\AndroidManifest.xml
Added file D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\build.xml
Added file D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\proguard-project.txt
¡Á??????¨°???? D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\\libs\ ??????????
¡Á??????¨°???? D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\\assets\ ??????????
Buildfile: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: myapp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for myapp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1.2
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for myapp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\classes
      [dex] input: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\guava-r09.jar
      [dex] input: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\gcm.jar
      [dex] input: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\nimblekit.jar
      [dex] input: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\commons-codec.jar
      [dex] input: D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\sqlcipher.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\guava-r09.jar -> guava-r09-6b26029ba5c5c64deca7abc18bdbd46a.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\gcm.jar -> gcm-b67a455e8cf4e7928c0b82a43c0eaf71.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\nimblekit.jar -> nimblekit-55e21e61378ef4231d2762729fb533e8.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\commons-codec.jar -> commons-codec-a607d24060085016c6270afbd6fb2bd5.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\libs\sqlcipher.jar -> sqlcipher-98f481e88e52b1031a529d6932a3c287.jar
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into D:\wamp\www\myapp\build\native-package-mobile\myapp\packager.json\bin\classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.nio.BufferOverflowException
       [dx]   at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:519)
       [dx]   at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putShort(HeapByteBuffer.java:315)
       [dx]   at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeShort(Dex.java:818)
       [dx]   at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeTypeList(Dex.java:870)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$3.write(DexMerger.java:437)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$3.write(DexMerger.java:423)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeUnsorted(DexMerger.java:317)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeTypeLists(DexMerger.java:423)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:163)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

BUILD FAILED
D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:284: null returned: 2

Total time: 17 seconds
""D:/Program Files/android-sdk-windows/sdk\tools\android" create project --target android-16 --name myapp --activity STActivity --path "D:\wamp\www\myapp/build/native-package-mobile/myapp/packager.json\/" --package com.xiubo.myapp"
Could not run ant with error: 1
Failed to package application

[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
[ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Targ
[ERR] et.java:413)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 27 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\myapp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\myapp\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\myapp\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:114: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\myapp\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:98: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\myapp\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:7: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
```

Answer (score 0):

check your sdk path properly and try following in packager.json file
and change to 
"sdk":"D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools"